# User registration form makes multiple records to access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

[image: It saves multiple record]

```
command.CommandText = "insert into Tunnukset (Käyttäjänimi,Salasana) values('" + txtkäyttäjä.Text + "','" + txtsal.Text + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();                                      //command.CommandText = "insert into Tunnukset (Käyttäjänimi,Salasana) values('" + txtkäyttäjä.Text + "','" + txtsal.Text +  "')";
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int count = 1;
while (reader.Read())
{
    count++;
}
if (txtkäyttäjä.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Käyttäjänimi kentt� tyhj�");//username field empty
    this.Hide();
    Form6 frm6 = new Form6();
    frm6.ShowDialog();
}
if (txtsal.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Salasana kentt� tyhj�");//passoword field empty
    this.Hide();
    Form6 frm6 = new Form6();
    frm6.ShowDialog();
}
else if (count > 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Käyttäjänimi varattu");//username taken
    this.Hide();
    Form6 frm6 = new Form6();
    frm6.ShowDialog();
}

if (txtsal.Text != txtvarmista.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("salasana ei t�sm��");//password do not match
}
else if (count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Tunnusten luominen onnistui");//Signup successfull

    con.Close();
    this.Hide();
    Form5 f5 = new Form5();
    f5.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: 1) Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. 2) Why do you check for emptyness **after** executing SQL query?

Comment: it saves the record twice to the database, how i fix it?

Comment: The fact that a method is named _ExecuteReader_ doesn't mean that it just reads records. It still executes first the Command's CommandText and then expects that command to returns a set of records to read. But if the command text is an INSERT is still executed. So you insert two times. One with ExecuteNonQuery and one time with ExecuteReader. Remove the ExecuteReader

Comment: Steve thank you very much, thats  the answer we have been looking for a week for now. thank you and sorry for the poor wording, bad english and unfamiliar to the website.

Comment: @Steve shouldn't it be "*remove the `ExecuteNonQuery`*"? As he seems to need the result?

Comment: @Rafalon what result? If he needs to know if the record has been inserted or not then he should look at the return of ExecuteNonQuery (the number of rows added/changed/deleted by the command) ExecuteReader cannot give him this info

Comment: @Steve right. This code obviously needs improvements, though

Comment: Yes, he needs also to consider the Sql Injection problem. A good answer should take care of that problem also. Too busy now.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer as stated by [@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve)

Your `INSERT` statement is executed twice:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

You should remove one of these calls depending on what you want to do after.

---

### Additional stuff you should take in consideration

1. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection:

   ```
   command.CommandText = "insert into Tunnukset (Käyttäjänimi,Salasana) values('" + txtkäyttäjä.Text + "','" + txtsal.Text + "')";
   ```

   You should consider using parameterized query to get rid of this vulnerability.
2. You check for username and password emptyness **after** you execute the query.
   Consider moving those blocks before the query part:

   ```
   if (txtkäyttäjä.Text == "")
   ```

   and

   ```
   if (txtsal.Text == "")
   ```
3. You should have a **`SELECT`** query if you want to check if the name is already taken.

   ```
   else if (count > 1)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Käyttäjänimi varattu");//username taken
       this.Hide();
       Form6 frm6 = new Form6();
       frm6.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```

   You are telling the user that his username is already taken **after** inserting it, so it's already too late.

---

### Pseudo-code attempt

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
{
    // tell username is empty
}
else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
{
    // tell password is empty
}
else if(password != passwordConfirmation)
{
    // tell passwords do not match
}
else if(UserAlreadyExists(username))
{
    // tell username is taken
}
else
{
    if(InsertUser(username, password))
    {
        // tell sign-in successfull
    }
}

private bool UserAlreadyExists(string username)
{
    // use SELECT parameterized query
    // return user existance (true or false)
}

private bool InsertUser(string username, string password)
{
    // use INSERT parameterized query
    // return success (true or false)
}
```